# How do I change the color of each tab?

Tags: vb.net

I have a form that has four tabs on it I would like each tab to be a different color. The only thing I have been able to find on the internet is how to change the color of the selected tab and the rest of the tabs stay the original color. I have not found anything to give each tab its own color. The code I currently have is.

```
Private Sub TabControl1_DrawItem(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.DrawItem

        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
        Dim tp As TabPage = TabControl1.TabPages(e.Index)
        Dim br As Brush
        Dim sf As New StringFormat

        Dim r As New RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y + 2, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height - 2)

        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

        Dim strTitle As String = tp.Text

        If TabControl1.SelectedIndex = e.Index Then

            'this is the background color of the tabpage header
            br = New SolidBrush(Color.LightSteelBlue) ' chnge to your choice
            g.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds)

            'this is the foreground color of the text in the tab header
            br = New SolidBrush(Color.Black) ' change to your choice
            g.DrawString(strTitle, TabControl1.Font, br, r, sf)

        Else

            'these are the colors for the unselected tab pages 
            br = New SolidBrush(Color.Blue) ' Change this to your preference
            g.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds)
            br = New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
            g.DrawString(strTitle, TabControl1.Font, br, r, sf)

        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Quote: `' Change this to your preference`.  Yes, good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two things that you need to do:

First is to change the DrawMode of the TabControl and set it to OwnerDrawFixed

[image: drawmode]

And the second is to handle the TabControl DrawItem event

Here is an example:

```
 Private Sub TabControl1_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.DrawItem
    Select Case e.Index
        Case 0
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.Red), e.Bounds)
        Case 1
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.Blue), e.Bounds)
        Case 2
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.Magenta), e.Bounds)

    End Select

    Dim paddedBounds As Rectangle = e.Bounds
    paddedBounds.Inflate(-2, -2)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(TabControl1.TabPages(e.Index).Text, Me.Font, SystemBrushes.HighlightText, paddedBounds)


End Sub
```

And here is what it looks like (I change the tab colors of the first three tab pages only, the others can be done easily by adding new cases to select case)

[image: tab colors]

Comment: This worked for me.  It is kind of odd that ownerdrawfixed makes the tab caption disappear.

Answer (score -1):

Is TabControl1 a Tab control you are adding to the form via the designer?  Why not just set the TabBackColor property for each tab when you create it there?

If not (you do have to do it via code), just use a loop to cycle through each tab in the TabControl1's collection of tab pages (TabControl1.TabPages) and set the TabBackColor property for each there.

Comment: I believe the original question was to change the color of the tab itself and not the back color of whole tab.  Additionally you have access to the properties at design time always so it would not necessitate programmatically changing the back color if you had not done it on onset.